# oracle NSL_Parameters: session vs database

Tags: oracle

I am having issues with a numeric format on my db.

I checked the NSL_Parameters and there is a difference between the database ones and session ones.

Can someone explain me if on this case, the queries will have the session format or the database one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your queries will always use the session NLS_Parameters. Actually most of all NLS_Parameters on database are only used to define the default session parameters if they are not set.

I think `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is the only NLS_Parameter which is relevant only on database level and cannot be changed on session level.